# drawing the circuit with the equivalent impedance

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz

could you help me to change the following code to the figure which I have attached?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[american]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering  
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw (0,3)
to[V,v<=$V_s$] (0,0)
(0,3) to[ R, R=$ \SI{4.5}{\ohm}$] (3,3) 
(3,3) to[ L=$j\SI{1.5}{\ohm}$] (6,3) 
(0,2.2) to[ open, v=$V$] (6.5,2.2) 
(6,3) to [R=$ \SI{25}{\ohm}$] (6,0)
(6,3) to[short] (8,3)
(8,3) to [L=$ j\SI{20}{\ohm}$] (8,0)
(8,3) to[short, -*] (10,3)
(10,0) to[short, *-] (0,0)
(10.2,3) to[ open, v=$V_o$] (10.2,0) 
(6,0) to[short] (0,0);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Annotation `Z_2`  is confusing, you are referring to the impedance of the line segment or the impedance of the two parallel components? In my understanding, `Z_2` is zero ohm because we assume the line segment is a pure conductor. Hmm...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[siunitx ]{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, arrows.meta, calc}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,calligraphy}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
    \draw 
    (0,3)               to[american voltages, V, v_=$V_s$, ]      (0,0)
    (0,3) coordinate(c) to[ R, R=$ {4.5}$]                              (2,3) 
                        to[ L=$j{1.5}$]                                 (4,3) coordinate(d) 
                        to[short, -*]                                   (4,3)
                        to [R=$ {25}$]                                  (4,0) coordinate(e)
                        to[short, -*]                                   (4,0)
    (4,3)               to[short, -*]                                   (6,3)
                        to [L=$ j{20}$]                                 (6,0) coordinate(f)
                        to[short, -*]                                   (6,0)
    (6,3)               to[short, -o]                                   (8,3) coordinate(g);
    \draw
    (10,1.5) coordinate(a) to [C=$-j{5}$]                           ++ (0,0.3) coordinate(b);
    \draw[dashed]
    (8,3)               to[short]                                       (10,3)
                        to                                              (b);
    \draw[dashed]   
    (a)                 to[short]                                       (10,0)
                        to                                              (8,0);
    \draw   
    (8,0) coordinate(h) to[short, o-]                                   (0,0);
\draw [decorate, decoration={calligraphic brace, mirror,amplitude=8pt}] ($(c.south)+(0.5,-4pt)$) -- node[below=2ex] {$Z_1$} ($(d.south)+(-0.5,-4pt)$);
\draw [decorate, decoration={calligraphic brace, mirror,amplitude=8pt}] ($(e.south)+(0,-4pt)$) -- node[below=2ex] {$Z_2$} ($(f.south)+(0,-4pt)$);
\node[below=1ex] at (8,3) (){+};
\node[above=1ex] at (8,0) (){--};
\node at( $(g)!0.5!(h) $)(){$V_0$};
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you Bibra.

Answer (score 6):

For exercise:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[american]{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,
                calligraphy}
\tikzset{BC/.style args = {#1/#2}{decorate,
        decoration={calligraphic brace, amplitude=2mm,
        pre =moveto, pre  length=2mm,
        post=moveto, post length=2mm,
        raise=#1,
              #2},% for mirroring of brace
        thick,
        pen colour=red}
        }
\ctikzset{bipoles/capacitor/height=0.5,
          bipoles/capacitor/width=0.1,
          }

\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}
\draw   (0,3)   to[V, a=$V_s$]  (0,0)            coordinate (aux0)
        (0,3)   to[R=$\SI{4.5}{\ohm}$]  ++ (2,0)
                to[L=$j\SI{1.5}{\ohm}$] ++ (2,0) coordinate (aux1)
                to[R=$\SI{25}{\ohm}$,*-*]   ++ (0,-3)
        (aux1)  -- ++ (1.5,0)                    coordinate (aux2)
                to[L=$j\SI{20}{\ohm}$,*-*]  ++ (0,-3)
        (aux2)  to[short,-o]            ++ (2, 0) coordinate[label=$a$] (aux3)
                to[open, v=$V_o$]       ++ (0,-3) node[below] {$b$}
                to[short,o-]            (aux0);
\draw[densely dashed]   
        (aux3)  to [short,o-] ++ (1,0) 
                to[C=$-j\SI{5}{\ohm}$]  ++ (0,-3)
                to [short,-o] (aux0 -| aux3);
\draw[BC=3mm/mirror]   
        (0,3) -- node[below=5mm] {$Z_1$}  (aux1); 
\draw[BC=1mm/mirror]   
        ([xshift=-4mm] aux0 -| aux1) -- node[below=3mm] {$Z_2$}  ([xshift=4mm] aux0 -| aux2);
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**
In the case, that you like to have `cute inductance` and solid capacitor's bars, then by considering of @Rmano comment below (@Rmano thank you very much for your help), the MWE can be:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[american, cute inductors]{circuitikz} % <---
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,
                calligraphy}
\tikzset{BC/.style args = {#1/#2}{decorate,
        decoration={calligraphic brace, amplitude=2mm,
        pre =moveto, pre  length=2mm,
        post=moveto, post length=2mm,
        raise=#1,
              #2},% for mirroring of brace
        thick,
        pen colour=red},
        }
\ctikzset{bipoles/capacitor/height=0.5,
          bipoles/capacitor/width=0.1,
          }

\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}
\draw   (0,3)   to[V, a=$V_s$]  (0,0)            coordinate (aux0)
        (0,3)   to[R=$\SI{4.5}{\ohm}$]  ++ (2,0)
                to[L=$j\SI{1.5}{\ohm}$] ++ (2,0) coordinate (aux1)
                to[R=$\SI{25}{\ohm}$,*-*]   ++ (0,-3)
        (aux1)  -- ++ (1.5,0)                    coordinate (aux2)
                to[L=$j\SI{20}{\ohm}$,*-*]  ++ (0,-3)
        (aux2)  to[short,-o]            ++ (2, 0) coordinate[label=$a$] (aux3)
                to[open, v=$V_o$]       ++ (0,-3) node[below] {$b$}
                to[short,o-]            (aux0);
% capacitor as capacitorshape node with dashed connections
\path   (aux3)  -- node (c) [right=10mm,
                             capacitorshape, fill=white, solid, rotate=90,
                             label=below:$-j\SI{5}{\ohm}$] {} (aux0 -| aux3);
\draw[densely dashed] 
        (aux3)  to [short,o-] ++ (1,0) to (c.right) 
        (c.left)to (aux0 -| c) to [short,-o] (aux0 -| aux3);
% 
\draw[BC=3mm/mirror]
        (0,3) -- node[below=5mm] {$Z_1$}  (aux1);
\draw[BC=1mm/mirror]
        ([xshift=-4mm] aux0 -| aux1) -- node[below=3mm] {$Z_2$}  ([xshift=4mm] aux0 -| aux2);
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: ah yes -- but the tricky part was getting the solid lines for the capacitor -- had to refer the documentation for that -- also I doubt that ohm symbol is to be inserted once the values are split into real and imaginary parts -- the inductance needs to be spiral of course as required by the OP --  but still +1 for the exercise :)

Comment: I am curious, is it possible to draw circuits without specifying explicitly the coordinates `(x,y)` ?  We don't specify explicitly the coordinate when drawing flow chart, right?

Comment: @jsbibra, from OP MWE follows, that (s)he like american style of drawing (BTW, showed image is terrible poor quality), solid lines for capacitor symbol: why should be if element is optional? However, if you like to have this, then just replace existed drawing of load by `\draw[densely dashed, shorten <>=2pt]
        (aux3)  -| ++ (1,-1.3) coordinate (c1);
\draw[densely dashed, shorten <>=2pt]
        (aux0 -| aux3) -| ++ (1,1.3) coordinate (c2);
\draw (c1) to[C=$-j\SI{5}{\ohm}$,bipoles/thickness=3]  (c2);`, where `shorten <>/.style = {shorten <=#1, shorten >=#1}`

Comment: @KimJongUn, for bipole elements you need to use one of coordinate sistem: *absolute*, or *relative* For more details see  or mix of bot as is used in mine answer. For nodes you can stick in their placement as you use in drawing flowcharts. For more details see package documentation.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: @Zarko you can also position a bare capacitor with `node[capacitorshape, rotate=90]` and then use the `left` and `right` anchors to connect it with dashed lines.

Comment: @Rmano, thank you very much for info. I will consider this in addendum to answer (I will write it at evening). To be honest, I hope that you will suggest some better solution as I propose in y comment :-).